# Запрос JOIN для SQL базы данных

Tags: sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будут созданы таблицы с данными клиента(Customer_ID,First_name, Last_name, Phone_number )-таблица c учетом заказов(Order_Id,Customer_ID, Date, Time)-таблица заказов с видом услуг(Order_ID, Product_ID)-таблица список оказываемых услуг(Product_ID, name_desctiption, price).
Нужно чтобы выводил бы последние n операций и их стоимость по конкретному клиенту используя JOIN запрос. заранее прошу прощения за SQL не шарю

Comment: Вы уже задавали этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1347186/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-sql).

Comment: @0xdb, с тем вопросом не помогли, а здесь человек даже постарался что-то сделать

Comment: Если не шарите в `SQL`, почитайте какие-то основы хотя бы для начала.

Comment: @SergeyK. так вроде там и указано, что надо переформулировать и отредактировать, а не новые плодить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем Вам таблица **OrderProduct**? Но сделал с ней на скорую руку.

```
SELECT TOP (10) -- n записей
-- Здесь вставить требуемы таблицы и столбцы
   O.Order_Id,
   O.Customer_ID,
   P.Product_ID,
   P.name,
   P.price
FROM Order O
JOIN Customer C ON
   O.Customer_ID = C.Customer_ID 
JOIN OrderProduct OP ON
   O.Order_Id = OP.Order_ID
JOIN Product P ON
   P.Product_ID = OP.Product_ID
WHERE O.Customer_ID = 1 -- нужный клиент
ORDER BY O.Date DESC -- последние записи
```

Могу быть не прав по поводу `order by ... desc` и `top (10)`. Думаю кто бы захотел создавать таблицы и заполнять данными, то проверил бы.